# Java Get After Next Iterator Element

Tags: java, iterator

PROBLEM. Need to compare two nearby iterator elements in Java.

RESEARCH. Could be solved by recording outside previous iterated element.

QUESTION. Is there a direct way to get iterator element, that is after next?

Comment: Only by advancing the iterator.

Comment: If you use a `ListIterator` you can move in both directions, making it easy to do this. With an ordinary `Iterator` you cannot peek ahead.

Comment: Does "nearby" mean "consecutive", as in "right next to each other"? If so, what is wrong with the solution you gave as RESEARCH?